# Retreiving in between object name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the middle object name from firebase realtime database.
My database looks like:

[Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwUCu.png)

In this example I am interested in retrieving `rBRAalNLEyfEcGeCDjMUOQGxXIF2` in the **first** child.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get **rBRAalNLEyfEcGeCDjMUOQGxXIF2**  from realtime database.

1) If you know parant id then try this code to get **rBRAalNLEyfEcGeCDjMUOQGxXIF2**

```
 final DatabaseReference realTimeDataBaseRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friend_request").child("cUCvOB7EDDcBQeffxvPslG2pz2A2");
       realTimeDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
             for(DataSnapshot item1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.i("check_middle_value",""+item1.getKey());
             }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
          }
       });
```

2) If You don't know parent key then try this code.

```
final DatabaseReference realTimeDataBase=
           FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friend_request").child("cUCvOB7EDDcBQeffxvPslG2pz2A2");
        realTimeDataBase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
              for(DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                 realTimeDataBase.child(item.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                       for(DataSnapshot item1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                          Log.i("check_middle_value",""+item1.getKey());
                       }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                    }
                 });
                 break;
              }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
           }
        });
```